# Executing JavaScript returned from a .post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I want JavaScript to execute the data that is returned from a post. I have found several similar threads but nothing that has cleared it up for me. `eval()` throws an unexpected identifier error.

The post:

```
$.post("./save.php", 
  {
    'images_key' : images_array,
    'userid_key' : $('#userid').val(),
    'avatar_key' : $('#avatar_name').val()
  },
  function( data ) 
  {
    $( "#responseText" ).val( data );
    eval(data);
  }
);
```

The post is returning:

```
$('.frame').html2canvas({
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
    //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
    $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    //Submit the form manually
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
  }
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

MORE INFO:

On button click I'm calling this function:

```
function saveCSS() {

    var id_data = $(".frame div img").map(function() {
      return $(this).attr("id");
    }).get();

    var title_data = $(".frame div img").map(function() {
      return $(this).attr("title");
    }).get();

    var width_data = $(".frame div img").map(function() {
      return $(this).css("width");
    }).get();

    var height_data = $(".frame div img").map(function() {
      return $(this).css("height");
    }).get();

    var top_data = $(".frame div:has(img)").map(function() {
      return $(this).css("top");
    }).get();

    var left_data = $(".frame div:has(img)").map(function() {
      return $(this).css("left");
    }).get();

    var zindex_data = $(".frame div:has(img)").map(function() {
      return $(this).css("z-index");
    }).get();


    var images_array = [];
       $.each(id_data, function (index, value) {
        images_array.push(value);
        images_array.push(title_data[index]);
        images_array.push(width_data[index]);
        images_array.push(height_data[index]);
        images_array.push(top_data[index]);
        images_array.push(left_data[index]);
        images_array.push(zindex_data[index]);
    });

    $.post("./save.php", 
      {
        'images_key' : images_array,
        'userid_key' : $('#userid').val(),
        'avatar_key' : $('#avatar_name').val()
      },
      function( data ) 
      {
        // $( "#responseText" ).val( data );
        // console.log(data);
        eval(data);
      }
    );
}
```

The file save.php contains:

```
.
.
.
echo "
$('.frame').html2canvas({
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
        document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    }
});
";
.
.
.
```

`console.log(data)` logs the `echo` as per expected however, in Chrome's console, when I execute `saveCSS()`, I see:

```
function( data ) 
      {
        // $( "#responseText" ).val( data );
        // console.log(data);
        eval(data);
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier**
      }
    );
```

I'm afraid I do not understand why I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to execute the dat that is returning you have to eval it e.g.

```
$.post("./save.php", 
  {
    'images_key' : images_array,
    'userid_key' : $('#userid').val(),
    'avatar_key' : $('#avatar_name').val()
  },
  function( data ) 
  {
    $( "#responseText" ).val( data );
    eval(data);
  }
);
```

That said unless you absolutely trust the code you are receiving from the server, I wouldn't recommend executing the data as it could lead to a [XSS vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) in your site.

Comment: I'm getting an unexpected identifier error...  :-/

Comment: Sound's like there is a syntax error in the code your are executing. Try console.log(data); so see if there has been any modification to the code between you writing it and the server.

Comment: Hmm...it logs exactly what it should be returning. `$('.frame').html2canvas({
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
    //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
    $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    //Submit the form manually
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
  }
});`

Comment: There has been a syntax error created by your comments. Change your comments to be like `/*Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string) */` and it should work. The issue is that your server is removing the end lines so single line comments will break your script.

Comment: I deleted the comments and now it's logging this: `$('.frame').html2canvas({
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
      $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
      document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
  }
});` However `eval(data)` is still throwing that error.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error that code runs fine for me. See here : http://i.imgur.com/o3e2Fwh.png

Comment: I added more information to my post. I really have no idea why I'm getting the error. Thank you for your help Shane.

Comment: It's still throwing the error but the script is being executed....as long as it's working : )